# LAG and/or LEAD alternative without window function in Pstgresql

Tags: database, analytics, data-analysis

Well I'm using Postgresql(but it won't matter if you can advise a solution in any SQL syntax), I have a table like

| employee | department | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 30,000 |
| 2 | sales | 25,000 |
| 3 | marketing | 45,000 |
| 4 | marketing | 55,000 |

so on...

What I want to achieve is:

| employee | department | salary | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 30,000 | 0/null |
| 2 | sales | 25,000 | 5,000 |
| 3 | marketing | 45,000 | 0/null |
| 4 | marketing | 55,000 | 10,000 |

So technically I want to extract the value difference of consecutive rows, however I can't use the window functions (I don't know why, but it is must to avoid in this challenge)
in a perfect world, we'd be able to do lag() or lead() functions partitioned by department name and store the value difference in other column, but I don't know how to do it without them.

I tried subqueries multiple ways, but every time I ended up having NULL or 0 in new a column

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `self-join` to table itself and join each employee with the previous row within the same department.

```
SELECT t1.employee, t1.department, t1.salary, ABS(t2.salary - t1.salary) AS difference
FROM tab t1
LEFT JOIN tab t2
ON t1.department = t2.department AND t1.employee = t2.employee +1
```

Comment: thank you, and one more thing, what if employee id numbers are not in order ?

Comment: You have to have an order, there are several options to add the order in the same query but it gets quite complicated, it would be better to add a new column `row_order` in the table or generating a view